# Constructing likelihood for a statistical functional

Tags: estimation, likelihood, sufficient-statistics, profile-likelihood

I'm a bit confused about something that I've seen in several engineering papers.  Suppose we have a random variable $X$ with unknown distribution $p(x)$.  We're interested in the value of a statistical functional

$$
y = \Bbb{E}_X[f(x)] = \int f(x)p(x)dx
$$ To estimate $y$, we'll collect an i.i.d. dataset $\mathcal{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$, then estimate $y$ via some estimator $\hat{y}$.  The question is, does it always make sense to construct the likelihood function

$$
\mathcal{L}(y\vert\mathcal{X})?
$$ If the single parameter $y$ is not a sufficient statistic for $p$, I assume the answer is no - that we must consider other parameters $\theta$, which may or may not be nuisance parameters.  As an example, suppose we know (or model) that $p(x)$ is normal, so that the sufficient statistics for $p$ are $(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Then, if we want to estimate something like $y = \Bbb{E}[\exp(x)]$, we can't just consider $\mathcal{L}(y\vert\mathcal{X})$ - we need to consider $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ somehow, even though I "don't really care about them" (I only want an estimate of $y$).  Is my reasoning correct?